# Error when installing Microsoft.Net.Http in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to install  installing Microsoft.Net.Http in xamarin but it is throwing me error

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Any solution for it  ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please install Microsoft.Bcl.Build first, then install Microsoft.Net.Http.
I have same issue then i am solved by this way.

Comment: This works, should be the accepted answer. Thanks jesto paul!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build in all your projects with the highest Build Number possible. Microsoft.Net.Http is dependent on both.

I get this error once in a while and it is always, because not in all related projects is the Microsoft.Bcl assembly referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting details of error which i  developer can face when installing   Microsoft.Net.Http
1 : First error throw error is like 
  " Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14 : ' does not exist in project 'App1.Droid'
Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14 : ' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Projects\App1\packages' "
Yes, that's the wrong package name. It added a " : " at the end.

**Soultion :**

You have to do it manually by changing  the WinRT.csproj with a text editor and removing ":" 
2: Second problem can be

" Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."
**Solution** 
It can solved by either  installing Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14 and for reference

1) Right click on reference of PCL

2)Select any one reference and right click on

3) select view in browser options

4) all objects are listed then select system.net.http

5) on the top of window you will see little icon to add reference to selected project